# Adaptive Finite Element; Laplace equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm currently attempting to turn my code for solving the laplace equation using finite element approximations into an adaptive one using the dual weighted residual as my error estimator: i.e. my indicator for element i: $\eta_i = (f[i] - \sum_0^N A_{ij}U_h[j])*z[i]$. i.e. I set up f, A and z over a very fine mesh and solve U_h over the normal mesh then interpolate it so i can perform the above operation.

I am solving for the dual solution z relatively simply; i.e. B(v,z) = Q(v) where B is the stiffness matrix and Q is a vector of 0s with 1 at the quantity of interest.

However the errors do not behave how they should; as an example i got the mesh to just increase from 10 in uniform multiples of 10 until 150. However these are the error estimates (as solved above):

```
0.0335462065038
0.0335462065038
0.0335462065038
0.0335462065038
0.0335462065038
0.0333608591916
0.0335462065038
0.0334614504804
0.0333158830798
0.0335462065038
0.0334317537862
0.0333344104201
0.0335441544821
0.0334327061457
```

They seem to drop then grow, drop then grow repeatedly and i have no idea why, does anybody have any clues what could be causing this?

Thanks,
James

Comment: [This site](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) might be more appropriate.